# Wrap around template in jsRender

Tags: javascript, templating, jsrender, jsviews

I am trying to wrap a piece of my template with plain HTML. Or in code:

```
{{expandable}}
     CONTENT
{{/expandable}}
```

should turn into:

```
<div class="expandable closed">
  <div class="header lowercase">
    <img src="/Control/Svg?picture=EdgeBracket_Right" style="height: 35px; position: relative; top: 10px;"/>
  </div> 
  <div class="content">
    CONTENT
  </div>
</div>
```

Things I tried so far:
*Custom tag approach*

```
$.views.tags("expandable", function() {
    return '<div class="expandable closed"><div class="header lowercase"><img src="/Control/Svg?picture=EdgeBracket_Right" style="height: 35px; position: relative; top: 10px;"/>' +
    '</div> <div class="content">' + this.tagCtx.render(content) + '</div></div>';
});
```

But inside `CONTENT` I can't access my data. [Or at least not the way I am used to.]

*Template approach*
I considered this example, which is technically closer to what I need:

```
{{boldp title /}}

...

$.views.tags("boldp", {
  template: "<p><strong>{{:~tag.tagCtx.args[0]}}</strong></p>"
});
```

But I don't know what to write instead of  `~tag.tagCtx.args[0]` if I want to wrap around something.

Which approach is *closer* to what I need? And how can I solve the remaining issues?

Comment: BTW this question is also interesting for JsViews. You may want to add that tag too...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do either:

```
$.views.tags("expandable", function() {
  return '<div class="expandable closed">\
    <div class="header lowercase">\
      <img src="/Control/Svg?picture=EdgeBracket_Right" style="height: 35px; position: relative; top: 10px;"/>\
    </div> \
    <div class="content">' +
      this.tagCtx.render()
  + '</div>\
  </div>';
});
```

or alternatively:

```
$.views.tags("expandable", {
    template: 
        '<div class="expandable closed">\
          <div class="header lowercase">\
            <img src="samples/data-link/question.jpg" style="height: 35px; position: relative; top: 10px;"/>\
          </div> \
          <div class="content">\
            {{include tmpl=#content||~tag.tagCtx.props.template/}}\
          </div>\
        </div>'
  });
```

Then if you put content such as:

```
  {^{expandable}}
    {^{for members}}
      <div data-link="name"></div>
    {{/for}}
  {{/expandable}}
```

(I am assuming JsViews here, but if you are just using JsRender you can write:

```
  {{expandable}}
    {{for members}}
      <div>{{:name}}</div>
    {{/for}}
  {{/expandable}}
```

for the non-data-linked equivalent)

the content should correctly access the data, such as `{^{for members}}`

You should also be able to do (for the first version using the function definition)

```
  {^{expandable tmpl='externalTemplate'/}}
```

or for the second - template based - version:

```
  {^{expandable template='externalTemplate'/}}
```

There is a related question here: https://github.com/BorisMoore/jsviews/issues/218